# nginx ignores my site configuration

Tags: nginx

I created site config file in dir `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled`

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name domain.com;
    gzip_types application/x-javascript text/css;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/nodeApp.info9000p.access.log;
    location / {
        proxy_pass    http://127.0.0.1:9000/;
    }
    location ~ ^/(min/|images/|bootstrap/|ckeditor/|img/|javascripts/|apple-touch-icon-ipad.png|apple-touch-icon-ipad3.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone.png|apple-touch-icon-iphone4.png|generated/|js/|css/|stylesheets/|robots.txt|humans.txt|favicon.ico) {
          root /root/Dropbox/nodeApps/nodeApp/9000/appdirectory-build; 
          access_log off;
          expires max;
        }
}
```

and restarted nginx:

`sudo /etc/init.d/nginx restart`

But `nginx` ignore my site config file and shows default page, when I request `domain.com` :

```
Welcome to nginx!

If you see this page, the nginx web server is successfully installed and working. Further configuration is required.

For online documentation and support please refer to nginx.org.
Commercial support is available at nginx.com.

Thank you for using nginx.
```

Comment: Your regex for your `location` block is very specific.  Why would you expect it to work for anything outside of what's in it?

Comment: This regex only for css and js, the rest requests shoud be proxied to localhost:9000. The same config worked perfect on another server.

Comment: Check DNS. Check protocol. Check, that your browser did not add `www` prefix to your request.

Comment: This question appears to belong on another site in the Stack Exchange network because its not about programming. Perhaps [Super User](https://www.superuser.com/) or [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't know how, but my configuration started to work well. Maybe because I restarted `nginx` instead of reload it.

Answer (score 1):

Where are your Wordpress-files located?

The default nginx *htdocs-root is /usr/share/nginx/html*

If you've installed the files at, say,  */usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress,* then you must change the root-setting in the file /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf to that directory, like this

```
server {
root /usr/share/nginx/html/wordpress;
}
```

Plese read the https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-nginx-mysql-php-lemp-stack-on-centos-7 article on how to set up nginx to work with the PHP-engine over socket (CentOS) if you have not already done so.